# Null Values in Scala Super Constructor?

Tags: scala, constructor, nullpointerexception

I'm getting some NPEs when working on some more object oriented pieces today - I'm not sure why but there are null values on the constructor for overridden fields.

Is there any way that I can fix this? Here is an example demonstrating the behaviour. You'll note that the base class' println causes null to be printed. If the base class tries to do anything with 'line' in the constructor of the base class, it will fire an npe.

```
scala> class Base {val line = "hey1"; println(line)}
defined class Base

scala> class Extended extends Base{ override val line = "hey2"; println(line)}
defined class Extended

scala> new Extended
null
hey2
res0: Extended = Extended@55991e21

scala> new Base
hey1
res1: Base = Base@1cc21a68
```

Eg here is an example demonstrating a null pointer exception.

```
scala> class Base { val line = "hello"; println(line.reverse)}
defined class Base
         ^
scala> class Extend extends Base { override val line ="exthello"; println(line.reverse);}
defined class Extend

scala> new Extend
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: The real question is what you'd expect to happen here. Scala's initialization order can be unintuitive, but would you expect the `println` in `Base` to briefly be able to see the `"hello"` before it gets overridden by `Extend`? Would you expect it to show `"exthello"` both times and thus behave more like an unordered initialization?

Comment: Just to elaborate, think of your declarations as `val line` (i.e., creating a field slot) and then a static initializer setting it equal to `"hello"` during the constructor run. The field unfortunately starts out as `null` until that constructor sets it to something else. In an ideal world that wouldn't be observable but it's one of the biggest gotchas for even experienced Scala developers using inheritance.

Comment: This issue is so notorious that it even has a [dedicated one-question FAQ](https://github.com/paulp/scala-faq/wiki) :)

Comment: @ghik thanks, you beat me to the head slap. Edit: I meant forehead slap, not a slap upside the head.

Comment: Thanks I figured out if you override in the params list it works but I'll read that!! thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to keep your structure, than use def or lazy val instead of val:

```
class Base {def line = "hey1"; println(line)}
class Extend extends Base { override def line ="exthello"; println(line);}
```

But better override in parameter list:

```
scala> class Base(val a: String = "hey1") {println(a)}
defined class Base

scala> new Base
hey1

scala> class Extend(override val a:String = "hey2") extends Base(a) {println(a)}

defined class Extend

scala> new Extend
hey2
hey2
res18: Extend = Extend@4d7efd4
```

Comment: This doesn't work if your constructor does some instantiation with your constructor.

Comment: I agree. Actually override in params list, as you said, is better.

Comment: If you edit your answer with params list I'll give you the checkmark :)

Answer (score 3):

Source: https://github.com/paulp/scala-faq/wiki/Initialization-Order

(Thanks Ghik - upvote the comment or the accepted answer instead of this answer - this is copied here for completeness and historical record).

**Initialization Order
Why is my abstract or overridden val null?**

Consider the following.

```
abstract class A {
  val x1: String
  val x2: String = "mom"

  println("A: " + x1 + ", " + x2)
}
class B extends A {
  val x1: String = "hello"

  println("B: " + x1 + ", " + x2)
}
class C extends B {
  override val x2: String = "dad"

  println("C: " + x1 + ", " + x2)
}
// scala> new C 
// A: null, null
// B: hello, null
// C: hello, dad
```

A 'strict' or 'eager' val is one which is not marked lazy.

In the absence of "early definitions" (see below), initialization of strict vals is done in the following order.

Superclasses are fully initialized before subclasses.
Otherwise, in declaration order.
Naturally when a val is overridden, it is not initialized more than once. So though x2 in the above example is seemingly defined at every point, this is not the case: an overridden val will appear to be null during the construction of superclasses, as will an abstract val.

There is a compiler flag which can be useful for identifying this situation:

-Xcheckinit: Add runtime check to field accessors.

It is inadvisable to use this flag outside of testing. It adds significantly to the code size by putting a wrapper around all potentially uninitialized field accesses: the wrapper will throw an exception rather than allow a null (or 0/false in the case of primitive types) to silently appear. Note also that this adds a runtime check: it can only tell you anything about code paths which you exercise with it in place.

Using it on the opening example:

```
% scalac -Xcheckinit a.scala
% scala -e 'new C'
scala.UninitializedFieldError: Uninitialized field: a.scala: 13
    at C.x2(a.scala:13)
    at A.<init>(a.scala:5)
    at B.<init>(a.scala:7)
    at C.<init>(a.scala:12)
```

Approaches for avoiding null values include:

Use lazy vals.

```
abstract class A {
  val x1: String
  lazy val x2: String = "mom"

  println("A: " + x1 + ", " + x2)
}
class B extends A {
  lazy val x1: String = "hello"

  println("B: " + x1 + ", " + x2)
}
class C extends B {
  override lazy val x2: String = "dad"

  println("C: " + x1 + ", " + x2)
}
// scala> new C 
// A: hello, dad
// B: hello, dad
// C: hello, dad
```

Usually the best answer. Unfortunately you cannot declare an abstract lazy val. If that is what you're after, your options include:

Declare an abstract strict val, and hope subclasses will implement it as a lazy val or with an early definition. If they do not, it will appear to be uninitialized at some points during construction.
Declare an abstract def, and hope subclasses will implement it as a lazy val. If they do not, it will be re-evaluated on every access.
Declare a concrete lazy val which throws an exception, and hope subclasses override it. If they do not, it will... throw an exception.
An exception during initialization of a lazy val will cause the right hand side to be re-evaluated on the next access: see SLS 5.2.

Note that using multiple lazy vals creates a new risk: cycles among lazy vals can result in a stack overflow on first access.

Use early definitions.

```
abstract class A {
  val x1: String
  val x2: String = "mom"

  println("A: " + x1 + ", " + x2)
}
class B extends {
  val x1: String = "hello"
} with A {    
  println("B: " + x1 + ", " + x2)
}
class C extends {
  override val x2: String = "dad"
} with B {  
  println("C: " + x1 + ", " + x2)
}
// scala> new C 
// A: hello, dad
// B: hello, dad
// C: hello, dad
```

Early definitions are a bit unwieldy, there are limitations as to what can appear and what can be referenced in an early definitions block, and they don't compose as well as lazy vals: but if a lazy val is undesirable, they present another option. They are specified in SLS 5.1.6.

Use constant value definitions.

```
abstract class A {
  val x1: String
  val x2: String = "mom"

  println("A: " + x1 + ", " + x2)
}
class B extends A {
  val x1: String = "hello"
  final val x3 = "goodbye"

  println("B: " + x1 + ", " + x2)
}
class C extends B {
  override val x2: String = "dad"

  println("C: " + x1 + ", " + x2)
}
abstract class D {
  val c: C
  val x3 = c.x3   // no exceptions!
  println("D: " + c + " but " + x3)
}
class E extends D {
  val c = new C
  println(s"E: ${c.x1}, ${c.x2}, and $x3...")
}
//scala> new E
//D: null but goodbye
//A: null, null
//B: hello, null
//C: hello, dad
//E: hello, dad, and goodbye...
```

Sometimes all you need from an interface is a compile-time constant.
Constant values are stricter than strict and earlier than early definitions and have even more limitations, as they must be constants. They are specified in SLS 4.1.